# Gson: Instantiate Interface from Json String

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using `Gson` to deserialize some json string (actually it's jwt) passed in by http header. The json contains:

```
[
    {"authority":"a1"},
    {"authority":"a2"},
    {"authority":"a3"},
             .
             .
             .
    {"authority":"a4"},
]
```

in `JsonElement`. 
And I'd like the above part to be deserialized into the field (in some class):

```
Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities
```

Where `GrantedAuthority` is an interface from Spring, it has an implementation `SimpleGrantedAuthority`.  `SimpleGrantedAuthority` has a constructor that takes a string:

public SimpleGrantedAuthority(String au) {this.au = au}

I need Gson to know the implementation class of interface `GrantedAuthority` in order to deserialize the json. I was trying:

```
public class GrantedAuthorityInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<GrantedAuthority> {
    @Override
    public GrantedAuthority createInstance(Type type) {
        // no such constructor
        GrantedAuthority ga = new SimpleGrantedAuthority();
        return ga;
    }
}
```

But since `SimpleGrantedAuthority` has no no-arg constructor, I need to provide an argument to the constructor. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How does the description relate to the title? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @waltersu I want to deserialize the json string to into that field, but it's an Interface type, I don't know how to program gson to instantiate that interface using the implementation `SimpleGrantedAuthority `

Comment: Why not deserialize them to `SimpleGrantedAuthority`, and create `Set<GrantedAuthority>` by yourself, and put them into the set?

Comment: @waltersu The json string has many other fields, and `Set<GrantedAuthority>` is also just one field of the class that I want to deserialize into.  I don't think I can deserialize other fields first and then make up the `Set<GrantedAuthority>` fields, because there's only one constructor that instantiates all fields.

Answer (score 1):

`InstanceCreator` won't work. According to [gson-user-guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types). you have 3 options:

> Option 1: Use Gson's parser API (low-level streaming parser or the DOM parser JsonParser) to parse the array elements and then  use Gson.fromJson() on each of the array elements.This is the preferred approach. Here is an example that demonstrates how to do this.
>
> Option 2: Register a type adapter for Collection.class that looks at each of the array members and maps them to appropriate objects. The disadvantage of this approach is that it will screw up deserialization of other collection types in Gson.
>
> Option 3: Register a type adapter for MyCollectionMemberType and use fromJson with Collection
>   This approach is practical only if the array appears as a top-level element or if you can change the field type holding the collection to be of type Collection.

You said

> And I'd like the above part to be deserialized into the field (in some class):

So, assume the "some class" is `MyClass`, and `authorities` is one field of `MyClass` for your json string (and there's other fields in `MyClass`). Below is an example code using method "Option 3":

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{ authorities: [\n" +
        "    {\"authority\":\"a1\"},\n" +
        "    {\"authority\":\"a2\"},\n" +
        "    {\"authority\":\"a3\"},\n" +
        "    {\"authority\":\"a4\"}\n" +
        "]}";

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(GrantedAuthority.class, new GrantedAuthorityTypeAdaptor());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    MyClass obj1 = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
    for (GrantedAuthority au : obj1.authorities) {
      SimpleGrantedAuthority sgau = (SimpleGrantedAuthority) au;
      System.out.println(sgau.authority);
    }
  }
}


class MyClass {
  Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

  // other fields
}


interface GrantedAuthority {
}

class SimpleGrantedAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {
  final String authority;

  public SimpleGrantedAuthority(String au) {
    this.authority = au;
  }
}

class GrantedAuthorityTypeAdaptor extends TypeAdapter<GrantedAuthority> {
  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter out, GrantedAuthority value) throws IOException {
    new Gson().getAdapter(SimpleGrantedAuthority.class).write(out, (SimpleGrantedAuthority) value);
  }

  @Override
  public GrantedAuthority read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    return new Gson().getAdapter(SimpleGrantedAuthority.class).read(in);
  }
}
```

The approach is to use `SimpleGrantedAuthorityAdaptor` as an adaptor for `GrantedAuthority`.

In order not to mess up other code, the `GsonBuilder` should be used only here. You should create a new `GsonBuilder` in your other code.

Comment: I got `NullPointerException` in `SimpleGrantedAuthority ` for `authority`. It seems that field is null.  One thing to note is that I used `JsonElement`. `jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(body.get("key"))` and then `gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Myclass.class)`.  `body.get("key")` actually returns a HashMap that I can use to instantiate Myclass.  It's kind of complicated because the token passed to me is actually a JWT token, I need to decrypt it first, which results in a HashMap.